# Printing multi-pages html, numbered the pages dynamically and footers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have one long page HTML page(4 printed pages, more or less). I'd like to be able to control where page breaks so to calculate height of page and to break in another page, and numbered the pages dynamically using javacript or jquery,and number of page to set on footers.

If not HTML, how about in Javascript or Jquery, can I do it that way? Any idea or suggestion?

CSS File:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page 
{
size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
#print-button {
    display: none;
}

@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
    footer {page-break-after: always;}

     p {page-break-inside: always;}

     table {page-break-before: always}

    div {page-break-after: always;}
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }

   .page-break  {  
    display:block;  
    page-break-before:always; 
    } 
    div.divFooter {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        <hr> {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}


 div.d0
      {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }
div.CSSTableGenerator
      {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }

#page-number:after {
    counter-increment: page_number;
    content: "Page " counter(page_number);
}
body {
    counter-reset: page_number;
}
</style>
```

And HTML file:

```
 <div id="d0" style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
<div id="d2" style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
 <p style="font-size:16px;"><?php echo $Article;?>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                   <td>Article</td>
                   <td>Quantity</td>
                   <td>Price</td>
                   <td>Stock</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Value</td>
                  <td>Value</td>
                  <td>Value</td>
                  <td>Value</td>
               </tr> 
        </table> 
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <hr>
</div>
```

This is the form of the multi tables that are dynamically using PHP.

Comment: Just a tip:  if you show some code, or partial code you will get more help.   This question is a bit too broad as there are many ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use the page-break CSS property.

In your CSS file,

```
@media print {
  .page-breaker { 
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

In your HTML,

```
<p>
 a very lengthy paragraph
</p>
<p class="page-breaker">
  another long paragraph
</p>
```

There will be a page break after the first < p >, when in print mode.

To break pages within a table, you can use this:

```
@media print {
  table { 
    page-break-inside:auto; 
  }
  tr { 
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-after:auto 
  }
}
```

To learn more about it, visit https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

Comment: I'm using this but doesn't work, I have multi tables for example:  

<div>Article 1</div> 
 <table> 
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Price</td>  
<td> quantity</td>
</tr>
</table>
And more than one tables ....
So when I print it appears <div>Article 1</div> in another page and table in another so I don't want to break at div but to check if the page size is going to be a4 and to set footer, for example <hr> tag.
Hope to have understood

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope this works for you to break the table up for the page. It would be great, if you can share you code next time.